# Local storage in Chrome Extension returns stale value when in Promise?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, es6-promise

I've been using a promise to return a value from local storage in a Chrome extension. It turns out that the promise returns a stale value if `LOGGED_IN` changes.

```
export const loggedIn = new Promise(resolve =>
  chrome.storage.local.get('LOGGED_IN', result => {
    resolve(result['LOGGED_IN'] === 'USER_IS_LOGGED_IN');
  }),
);
```

However this issue doesn't happen if I wrap the promise in a function.

```
export const loggedIn = () => new Promise(resolve =>
  chrome.storage.local.get('LOGGED_IN', result => {
    resolve(result['LOGGED_IN'] === 'USER_IS_LOGGED_IN');
  }),
);
```

sendMessage doesn't have this issue. I can use it directly and it never returns a stale value:

```
const getTabId = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'get-tab-it' });
```

Why do the two behave differently? Does sendMessage not also return a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with any `chrome` APIs. It is due to the way you're initialising variable `loggedIn`.

`loggedIn` is a `const` variable which is set to a `Promise` object. This `Promise` object will only be resolved once when you do `await loggedIn` and at that time value of key `LOGGED_IN` will be fetched from the `localStorage`.

Wrapping the promise in a function ensures that every time you call the function, a new `Promise` object is returned and the value of the key is fetched from localstorage each time.